# Write PowerShell object with CSV formatting directly to FTP

Tags: .net, powershell, csv, ftp

Is there a way in PowerShell to write an object directly to FTP?

For instance, say I need to read an XML file and send pertinent pieces somewhere. 
 I'd begin as follows:

```
$URL = 'https://example.org/portal/v1/report01.xml'
$Response = [xml]( Invoke-WebRequest $URL -Method Get )
$Response.REPORT01.row | Select-Object id, date, name, balance-due
```

I know I can chain this to create a CSV file ...

```
| Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\report01.csv" -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```

... and then FTP the file to its ultimate destination.

What I'm wondering is if there's away to avoid having to write to the disk.  So what I'd like to do is take the response, format it as CSV, and then beam it where it needs to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to upload an in-memory data to an FTP server is using [`WebClient.UploadString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstring):

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
$client.UploadString("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.csv", $contents)
```

---

To get object data as CSV in-memory, use [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) instead of `Export-Csv`:

```
$contents =
    (($data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine) +
    [Environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your response.  I just found the cmdlet ConvertTo-CSV, so I think I'm all set!